# Why did the SOAP service (jax-ws) is stopped on Linux OS after a time and WebServiceTransportException: Unauthorized [401]] throwed?

Tags: java, jax-ws, spring-ws

I have developed a soap application and am sending requests to the required service. The problem is that after some time an exception is thrown:

Stacktrace:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Unauthorized [401]] with root cause

org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Unauthorized [401]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleError(WebServiceTemplate.java:665) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:587) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:538) ~[spring-ws-core-4.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at
```

The functionality works in Windows, but in Linux (Rocky Linux) it stops working after some time (5-10 minutes).

Here is my configuration (some info are changed like URLs):

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomerPaymentClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.example.wsdl");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate(WebServiceTemplateBuilder builder, Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) throws Exception {

        return builder
                .setDefaultUri("https://service.example.com/WebPortalVC/PaymentWS")
                .setMarshaller(marshaller)
                .setUnmarshaller(marshaller)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Here is my client

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GPPPaymentClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
    private final WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;
    private final Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller;

    public InitiatePaymentResponse InitiatePayment(MessageHeader messageHeader, InitiatePayment InitiationRequest) {

        JAXBElement<InitiatePaymentResponse> object = (JAXBElement<InitiatePaymentResponse>) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(InitiationRequest, webServiceMessage -> {
            try {
                String namespaceSer = "http://services.ws.payment.example.net/";
                SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) webServiceMessage;
                SoapHeader header = soapMessage.getSoapHeader();
                header.addNamespaceDeclaration("ser", namespaceSer);

                ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
                MessageHeader soapHeader = objectFactory.createMessageHeader();
                soapHeader.setUserID(messageHeader.getUserID());
                soapHeader.setReceiverID(messageHeader.getReceiverID());
                soapHeader.setTransactionID(messageHeader.getTransactionID());
                soapHeader.setMessageDateTime(messageHeader.getMessageDateTime());
                JAXBElement<MessageHeader> headerElement = new JAXBElement<>(new QName("http://services.ws.payment.example.net/", "messageHeader"), MessageHeader.class, null, soapHeader);
                marshaller.marshal(headerElement, header.getResult());
                JAXBElement<InitiatePayment> bodyElement = new JAXBElement<>(new QName("http://test.ws.payment.example.net/", "InitiatePayment"), InitiatePayment.class, null, InitiationRequest);
                marshaller.marshal(bodyElement, soapMessage.getPayloadResult());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.info(e.toString());
            }
        });
        return object.getValue();
    }
}
```

Here I'm adding properties to trust ssl certificates from truststore

```
@Bean
public void addProperties() {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStoreLocation);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePassword);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", cacertLocation);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", cacertPassword);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56605045/why-did-secure-spring-ws-integration-return-unauthorized-401?rq=2

Comment: Yeah, it's working well. I'm receiving 401 after a while time only in Linux OS. I'm using the same versions of Java 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of years ago I encountered such a problem. The problem, as I understood it, was the JDK version. I changed JDK to another version (Amazon Coretto) and everything worked.